# replace point in duplicate columns names

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

When duplicate column names are found in my data frame, R automatically puts " . "and" 1 " (.1) in the name of the duplicate column.

```
ID      value1     value2    value3   ...    value1.1   value2.1   value3.1
22        4          3         6               3          5          6
```

I'm trying to use:

```
names(data) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(data))
```

but if there is more than one dot in the column name, then it changes them all, and I want it to change only the one that stands before 1:

```
ID      value.1.   value.2.  value.3.   ...    value.1..1   value.2..1   value.3..1
22        4          3         6                 3            5            6
```

I want:

```
ID      value.1.   value.2.  value.3.   ...    value.1._1   value.2._1   value.3._1
22        4          3         6                 3            5            6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `sub` to capture the match the `.` between the `.` and the 1 value (captured as a group) and in the replacement, specify the backreference of those captured groups and insert the `_`

```
sub("([a-z])\\.(1)$", "\\1_\\2",sub("(\\.)\\.(1)$", "\\1_\\2", names(data)))
```

Or this can be simplified as

```
sub("([a-z.])\\.(1)$", "\\1_\\2", names(data))
```

-testing

```
v1 <- c("value.1.", "value.2.", "value.1", "value.1..1", "value.2..1", "value.3..1")

sub("([a-z])\\.(1)$", "\\1_\\2", sub("(\\.)\\.(1)$", "\\1_\\2",  v1))
#[1] "value.1."   "value.2."   "value_1"    "value.1._1" "value.2._1" "value.3._1"
```

Or

```
sub("([a-z.])\\.(1)$", "\\1_\\2", v1)
[1] "value.1."   "value.2."   "value_1"    "value.1._1" "value.2._1" "value.3._1"
```

Comment: this is great, and if I still have a column with one point, then he does not want to change it

Comment: @GOGAGOGA can you test it.  It is not changing that case  i.e. `"value.1."` remains as such

Comment: for value.1. it works, but if value.1 that .1 does not change to _1

Comment: @GOGAGOGA i was looking at your second set of input/expected output in the post